# Merge two planes one above the other

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices

New to Blender here! I'm trying to build a rudimentary race track with Blender 2.79b which currently consists in:

- a square plane subdivided n times to create a terrain which will have bumps
- a track modeled using Array and Curve modifiers that fit to a Bezier curve.

What I'd like to achieve is merging the two planes so that:

- the track will be correctly rendered
- sculpting the terrain will affect the surrounding track

However, I may be going in the wrong direction trying to do this, so I'm grateful for any proposal that is better practice!

[image: Wireframe planes]
[image: Material rendering]

Comment: perhaps look at Shrinkwrap: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121908/project-road-on-a-landscape/121954#121954

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Zim in this case its best to use the **ShrinkWrap** or **KnifeProject**. The 1st one is more simple to use so thats what we try. I prepared the scene looking like this:

[image]

You could see the road above the terrain so now its good to **make the road subdivided** (preferably more that the terrain) for ShrinkWrap being possible so use Subdivide to achieve this result:

[image]

Its enough to acomplish what we want so now the modifier takes place. Add it and as a **target choose the terrain** object (in my case its "Plane"). Now use the settings as below (GREEN). As a **MODE use the Project** and dont forgot to **check the Negative projection** (in our case we have road above the surface so its negative). Also dont forget to **set the Offset to about 0.01** (lets try lowest value possible) to avoid overlapping faces.

[image]

Everything is done so hope it helps Buddy.

*Sincerely, Jan*

Comment: Hi Jan thanks for your answer which gives a satisfying result, but this does not help regarding my second expectation (sculpting the terrain will affect the surrounding track): sculpting a bump next to a curve will sculpt over the track...
I don't know if it's ever possible so I ended up drawing the track directly on the ground texture in an image editor. (upvoting anyway :)

Comment: Hi Zim it sound like a "glitch" cause it does not matter if You sculpt the terrain the road should be above it no matter what so please share the blend file here so I could look.

Comment: Here it is: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=28872486417056360452 (edit: reuploaded without textures)

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5525/ ... problem SOLVED ;). The reason for the error was that You did **not subdivide the basic mesh** as I mentioned in the step 2 of my answer. **Explore the file and especially the ROAD modifiers and settings**.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for you help Jan :) The terrain sculpting is very slow on my computer but it behaves exactly as I wish!

Comment: No problem happy to help.